# How to format markdown and all code in it?

Tags: formatting, markdown, github-actions

I have a bunch of markdown files in my github repo. As there are many members in the team, the syntax of markdown and code in markdown files are hard to be standardised.

What I want is:
Create a github action that modify those files automatically when there is a push.

I can't find a markdown prettifier that format the code as well. (e.g. putting spaces around '=')

The solutions that I can think out of are:

1. Use a CLI tool that can do all the stuff
2. Use a tool for markdown, use a script to filter all code in it and parse it to anther tool
3. Send http requests to those online prettifier if such CLI tools do not exist

Note: I have Java, Cpp, Swift and more in my markdown.

Any solution for this? I will be appreciated if the script could be provided (if needed).

Thanks.

Comment: This is not directly related to GitHub Actions. Once you find such a tool - if it exists - you can install it on GitHub Actions and run it. Perhaps [this markdown linter](https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint) helps?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. I have checked that out? I would like to ask, does it match my first or second solution? Does it format the file or just showing messages?

Answer (score 1):

If those `markdown` files are located in a `java` project, you may try [spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless).

For example, if you have a maven project, with spotless, just run `mvn spotless:apply`, it could fix all the styles / formatting issues of your markdown files automatically.